# Cassandra cluster manager and endpoint exception

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-sharp

I have 4 dependent working windows service in one solution and using cassandrasharp 3.1.4 and cassandra 2.0.6.

On the first one, I initialize clusterManager with; (**This code is just working on the first service, when i try to configure clusterManager in each of the services, these services doesn't start.**)

```
CassandraSharp.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

and this is my app.config;

```
<configSections>
    <section name="CassandraSharp" type="CassandraSharp.SectionHandler, CassandraSharp.Interfaces" />
  </configSections>

  <CassandraSharp>
    <Cluster name="main">
      <Endpoints>
        <Server>kml-vm-cas-001.cloudapp.net</Server>
      </Endpoints>
    </Cluster>
  </CassandraSharp>
```

and OnStop of each of services;

```
ClusterManager.Shutdown();
```

Process is simple, each of these services read string from different live stream, deserialize and push to cassandra.

```
      string query = null;
      ICqlCommand pocoCommand = null;
      Task task = null;
      using (ICluster iCluster = ClusterManager.GetCluster("main"))
      {
        query = string.Format("insert into Tvr.Zools (Part, Name, Ticks) values ('zools', '{0}', {1}) using ttl 86400;",
                  this.zools[i].Name,
                  dateTime.Ticks,
                );
        pocoCommand = iCluster.CreatePocoCommand();
        task = pocoCommand.Execute(query).AsFuture();
        task.Wait();

        query = string.Format("insert into Tvr.Temps (Part, Name, Ticks) values ('zools', '{0}', {1}) using ttl 10800;", this.zools[i].Name, dateTime.Ticks);
        pocoCommand = iCluster.CreatePocoCommand();
        task = pocoCommand.Execute(query).AsFuture();
        task.Wait();
      }
```

This works well for small streams but when these services starts to catch huge load of streams i got these exceptions;

```
System.ArgumentException: Can't find any valid endpoint
```

and for some of the services;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ClusterManager is not initialized
```

I tried this in each of services but didn't work;

```
CassandraSharp.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

//push process..

ClusterManager.Shutdown();
```

Sorry for any missing information, I'll edit if there is any.

Thanks already.

Answer (score 1):

CassandraSharp handles all of the connection management and pooling for you. All you have to do is run `CassandraSharp.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` one time per application. CassandraSharp will then open a connection for you as you need it. You should only call `ClusterManager.Shutdown();` when the app is shutting down. Here is a snippet [from the author of CassandraSharp](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cassandra-sharp-user/DG6lw9I9L0U/0ecRpZvcoooJ):

> Configure() must be called once and never more. If you want to shut
>   down all your clusters connections (let say your process is exiting),
>   then call Shutdown().
>
> Shutdown() is shutting down all your connections and services for the
>   whole process - it might have bad impact on the rest of your
>   application if you are connecting to several clusters in the same
>   process.

Even if you are connecting to multiple clusters you should define them in the XML config and still only call `Configure()` one time. So here is an example setup.

**Example XML Config**

```xml
<CassandraSharp>
<Cluster name="Dev">
  <Transport cl="ONE" cqlver="3.1.1" />
  <Endpoints>
    <Server>server1.test.com</Server>
  </Endpoints>
</Cluster>
<Cluster name="Prod">
  <Transport cl="ONE" cqlver="3.1.1" />
  <Endpoints>
    <Server>server1.test.com</Server>
    <Server>server2.test.com</Server>
  </Endpoints>
</Cluster>
</CassandraSharp>
```

**Sample Code**

Notice the `static cluster`. That will only exist one time in the application so you wont run into issues creating multiple instances.

```cs
public interface IClusterFactory
{
    ICluster GetCluster();
}

public class ClusterFactory : IClusterFactory
{
    private static ICluster cluster;

    public ICluster GetCluster()
    {
        if (cluster != null)
        {
            return cluster;
        }
        else
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            cluster = ClusterManager.GetCluster("Prod");
            return cluster;
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever you want to get a connection to Cassandra:

```cs
IClusterFactory factory = new ClusterFactory();
ICluster cluster = factory.GetCluster();
IPropertyBagCommand cmd = cluster.CreatePropertyBagCommand();
```

Don't worry about disposing or closing the cluster as that get's handled in CassandraSharp. Just do a `ClusterManager.Shutdown()` when the application shuts down.